# Uncaught Error: Automatic publicPath is not supported in this browser at content.js:1:8557

Tags: reactjs, webpack, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

i am new in react, after i run my application for testing the redux functionality, the chrome browser gives this error.

content.js:1 Uncaught Error: Automatic publicPath is not supported in this browser
at content.js:1:8557